# How do I make a code that, when the input is a list of your TikTok followers, make a list of all of them that have over ex. 10 000 followers?

Tags: javascript, python, html, arrays, web-scraping

How do I make a code that, when the input is a list of your TikTok followers, make a list of all that have over ex. 1000 followers?

Like I put in, for example, a .txt file of all my followers usernames on TikTok and it makes it into a list and then looks how many followers each individual follower has. That way I can see if any famous follows me.

I'm a beginner in programming.

Does not need to be good looking at all. I prefer html but other is ok.

This is what I've tried but it's only looking at one user at the time and you need to do the input manually, and its iframe:ing right from "realtimetiktok.com":

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TikTok Followers</title>

<style>
body {
  background-color: #ff004f;
}
</style>

</head>
<body style = "text-align:center">
<h1 style = "color:green;">
</br>
Write a TikTok username here
</h1>
 <div class="box red"></div>
</br></br></br>

<input autofocus required pattern="[^' ']+" type = "text" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="on" id="myInput">
 <button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">Get Value</button>

 <iframe id="myFrame" scrolling="no" src="https://www.realtimetiktok.com/?user=samthemans" style="border: 0px none; width: 1890px; height: 726px; overflow: hidden position: relative; left: -100px; top: -100px relative"> </iframe>
<script>
        function getInputValue(){
            // Selecting the input element and get its value 
            var inputVal = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
            let x = (inputVal);
    document.getElementById("myFrame").src = "https://www.realtimetiktok.com/?user=" + x;
}

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

output:
a list of all users that have over ex. 1000 followers and some details about them. Like this:

- [username 1]   1 326  followers
- [username 2]   14 836 followers
- [username 3]   1 482  followers

But the output can be in any other way as well.

Comment: Welcome to SO Konrad. I would suggest you start by learning how to get the JSON that the TikTok API returns and then you do a for loop over that array of results. Even better you can use the `some` array method to extract just the results from the array with over a thousand followers.

Comment: @MikePoole  Sorry, I'm really a beginner in coding. Can you please explain about _"the JSON that the TikTok API returns"_ and _"the `some` array method to extract just the results from the array with over a thousand followers."_
But thanks alot for the help!

Comment: The problem is that he isn't using an API, if you look at the site, there is no api, I think he just wants to scrape it

Comment: @Yodamaul Great point - it appears [it's been reverse-engineered](https://medium.com/@szdc/reverse-engineering-the-musical-ly-api-662331008eb3), which would simply add to the complexity of the end product the OP is attempting to build as a "beginner in coding".

Comment: @esqew agreed, but a basic webscraper shouldn't be that difficult even for a beginner imo.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said you seem a bit confused on how exactly to go about this and you may have picked a topic a bit too advanced for you. While no one here is going to write your code for you, I think you are going about this in the wrong direction if you do want to proceed with this. You need to do some webscraping to get your data. You added a python tag so I am assuming you know some python.

You need to know how to do the following for your idea to work:
1) Print console messages
2) Read from Text Files
3) Web Scrape -- Look at a library called Beautiful Soup, that will get you in the right direction

From there you just want to loop over each line in the text file, scrape for each one, and clean up what you get from scraping and print what you want.

That would be how I'd go about this, though that's assuming you have a cursory understanding of python.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think I would do all that in Python?

Comment: Yep! If you want to get fancy with it down the line and use HTML/CSS as well you could look at the flask library or something, but I'd focus on getting this down first